# Convert filename extension to UTI

Tags: macos, bash

How can you convert a filename extension string (like `png`) to a [Uniform Type Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Type_Identifier) (like `public.png`)?

I'm looking for a general purpose script or utility, not anything like `mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree <file>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way to do that is to use `UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag()`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSArray *args = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments];

    if ([args count] < 2) {
        printf("usage:\n");
        printf("uti <filenameExtension>\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    NSArray *extensions = [args
                 subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [args count] - 1)];

    for (NSString *filenameExtension in extensions) {
        NSString *utiType = (NSString *)UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(
                              kUTTagClassFilenameExtension,
                           (CFStringRef)filenameExtension, NULL);

        printf("%s\n", [utiType UTF8String]);
        [(NSString *)utiType release];
    }

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled `uti` executable and source code: [uti.zip](http://www.markdouma.com/developer/uti.zip)

Usage:

```
MacPro:~ mdouma46$ /Users/mdouma46/Developer/uti/uti png tga mov sdfad
public.png
com.truevision.tga-image
com.apple.quicktime-movie
dyn.age81g3dgqfwa
```

("unknown" file extensions are mapped to UTIs that begin with the `dyn.` prefix).

Answer (score 3):

In case this is primarily about convenience (I'm willing to delete though):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $# = 0 ] ; then
        echo "Fail param"
        exit 1
fi

ext=$1
export TMPDIR=$HOME/Library
t=$( mktemp -t getuti.XXXXXX )

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
        echo "Fail mktemp"
        exit 1
fi

mv $t $t.$ext

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
        echo "Fail mv"
        exit 1
fi

while true ;
do
        uti=$( mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree -raw -nullMarker $t $t.$ext )
        if [ "$uti" = "${uti//$t/}" ] ; then
                echo "$uti"
                rm -f $t.$ext
                exit 0
        fi
        sleep 1
done
```

Usage:

```
$ ./getuti.sh jpeg
(
    "public.jpeg",
    "public.image",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content"
)
$ ./getuti.sh gif
(
    "com.compuserve.gif",
    "public.image",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content"
)
$ ./getuti.sh mdown
(
    "net.daringfireball.markdown",
    "public.text",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content"
)
$ ./getuti.sh foobarbazqux
(
    "public.data",
    "public.item"
)
```

Comment: You wouldn't need to loop at the end if you `mdimport`ed the temp file.

Answer (score 2):

#### getuti

```
if [[ $# == 0 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: getuti extension ..."
    exit 1
fi
for x in $@; do
    f="/tmp/me.lri.getuti.$x"
    touch "$f"
    mdimport "$f"
    mdls -name kMDItemContentType "$f" | sed 's|.*"\(.*\)"|\1|'
    rm "$f"
done
```

#### Usage

```
$ getuti png pngooo
public.png
dyn.ah62d4rv4ge81a5xhr7108
```

Answer (score 0):

From version 1.5.2, [duti](http://duti.org/) (installation via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh): `brew install duti`) supports the `-e` option - undocumented as of 1.5.2 - which retrieves the UTI declaration associated with a specified filename extension:

```
duti -e .png
```

yields, e.g.:

```
identifier: public.png
description: Portable Network Graphics image
declaration: {
    UTTypeIdentifier = public.png
    UTTypeDescription = Portable Network Graphics image
    UTTypeConformsTo = public.image
    UTTypeTagSpecification = {
        com.apple.ostype = PNGf
        public.mime-type = image/png
        com.apple.nspboard-type = Apple PNG pasteboard type
        public.filename-extension = png
    }
}
```

Thus, to retrieve just the UTI for extension `.png`, use:

```
duti -e .png | awk '{ print $2; exit }' # -> 'public.png'
```